# c# foreach (property in object)... Is there a simple way of doing this?

Tags: c#, properties, foreach, generic-list

I have a class containing several properties (all are strings if it makes any difference).
I also have a list, which contains many different instances of the class.

While creating some unit tests for my classes I decided I wanted to loop through each object in the list and then loop through each property of that object...

I thought doing this would be as simple as...

```
foreach (Object obj in theList)
{
     foreach (Property theProperties in obj)
     {
         do some stufff!!;
     }
}
```

But this didnt work! :(
I get this error...

"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Application.Object' because 'Application.Object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Does anyone know of a way of doing this without tons of ifs and loops or without getting into anything too complex?

Comment: In the future, please don't say "It doesn't work" in a question. Instead, specify the problem you are having (compiler error, etc). Thanks!

Comment: Updated! Thanks for the heads up Robert

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   // do stuff here
}
```

Also please note that `Type.GetProperties()` has an overload which accepts a set of binding flags so you can filter out properties on a different criteria like accessibility level, see MSDN for more details: [Type.GetProperties Method (BindingFlags)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) Last but not least don't forget to add the "system.Reflection" assembly reference.

For instance to resolve all public properties:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in obj.GetType()
                                .GetProperties(
                                        BindingFlags.Public 
                                        | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
   // do stuff here
}
```

Please let me know whether this works as expected.

Comment: Once you have a handle on the objects properties, is there anyway of grabbing the value of each property? i.e. a Name or Postcode for example

Comment: Like this:
 propertyInfo .GetValue(obj, null)

Answer (score 48):

You can loop through all non-indexed properties of an object like this:

```
var s = new MyObject();
foreach (var p in s.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().GetParameters().Any())) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.GetValue(s, null));
}
```

Since `GetProperties()` returns *indexers* as well as simple properties, you need an additional filter before calling `GetValue` to know that it is safe to pass `null` as the second parameter.

You may need to modify the filter further in order to weed out write-only and otherwise inaccessible properties.

Comment: +1 for only doing something with the properties that can actually be used -- you might also want to filter out write-only properties.

Comment: @hvd It's an excellent point on the write-only properties! I've nearly forgotten about them. My code will crash if it encounters a property with `null` getter, but I'm sure OP will figure out how to get only the properties that he needs.

Answer (score 45):

Your'e almost there, you just need to get the properties from the type, rather than expect the properties to be accessible in the form of a collection or property bag:

```
var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

From there [you can access like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx):

```
property.Name
property.GetValue(obj, null)
```

With `GetValue` the second parameter will allow you to specify index values, which will work with properties returning collections - since a string is a collection of chars, you can also specify an index to return a character if needs be.

Comment: Did I upset somebody? I'm open to knowing what's wrong about this, otherwise I might never learn.

Comment: You probably got the downvote when your code was wrong (before your ninja edit).

Answer (score 22):

Sure, no problem:

```
foreach(object item in sequence)
{
    if (item == null) continue;
    foreach(PropertyInfo property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        // do something with the property
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you add this line? `if (item == null) continue;` personally, i think if you got a null object at that point, something went wrong a lot earlier and that is where the validation should be, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Dementic: Sure, we could say that the sequence is required to contain non-null references.

Answer (score 5):

I looked for the answer to a similar question on this page, I wrote the answers to several similar questions that may help people who enter this page.

**[Class List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1)**

List < T > class represents the list of objects which can be accessed by index. It comes under the System.Collection.Generic namespace. List class can be used to create a collection of different types like integers, strings etc. List class also provides the methods to search, sort, and manipulate lists.

**Class with property**:

```
class TestClss
{
    public string id { set; get; }
    public string cell1 { set; get; }
    public string cell2 { set; get; }
}
var MyArray = new List<TestClss> {
    new TestClss() { id = "1", cell1 = "cell 1 row 1 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 1 Data" },
    new TestClss() { id = "2", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 2 Data" },
    new TestClss() { id = "3", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 3 Data" }
};
foreach (object Item in MyArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row Start");
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in Item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var Key = property.Name;
        var Value = property.GetValue(Item, null);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Key, Value);
    }
}
```

OR, **Class with field**:

```
class TestClss
{
    public string id = "";
    public string cell1 = "";
    public string cell2 = "";
}
var MyArray = new List<TestClss> {
    new TestClss() { id = "1", cell1 = "cell 1 row 1 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 1 Data" },
    new TestClss() { id = "2", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 2 Data" },
    new TestClss() { id = "3", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 3 Data" }
};
foreach (object Item in MyArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row Start");
    foreach (var fieldInfo in Item.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        var Key = fieldInfo.Name;
        var Value = fieldInfo.GetValue(Item);
    }

}
```

OR, **List of objects** (without same cells):

```
var MyArray = new List<object> {
    new { id = "1", cell1 = "cell 1 row 1 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 1 Data" },
    new { id = "2", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 2 Data" },
    new { id = "3", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 3 Data", anotherCell = "" }
};
foreach (object Item in MyArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row Start");
    foreach (var props in Item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var Key = props.Name;
        var Value = props.GetMethod.Invoke(Item, null).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Key, Value);
    }
}
```

OR, **List of objects** (It must have the same cells):

```
var MyArray = new[] {
    new { id = "1", cell1 = "cell 1 row 1 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 1 Data" },
    new { id = "2", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 2 Data" },
    new { id = "3", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 3 Data" }
};
foreach (object Item in MyArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row Start");
    foreach (var props in Item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var Key = props.Name;
        var Value = props.GetMethod.Invoke(Item, null).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Key, Value);
    }
}
```

OR, **List of objects** (with key):

```
var MyArray = new {
    row1 = new { id = "1", cell1 = "cell 1 row 1 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 1 Data" },
    row2 = new { id = "2", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 2 Data" },
    row3 = new { id = "3", cell1 = "cell 1 row 2 Data", cell2 = "cell 2 row 3 Data" }
};
// using System.ComponentModel;  for TypeDescriptor
foreach (PropertyDescriptor Item in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(MyArray))
{
    string Rowkey = Item.Name;
    object RowValue = Item.GetValue(MyArray);
    Console.WriteLine("Row key is: {0}", Rowkey);
    foreach (var props in RowValue.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var Key = props.Name;
        var Value = props.GetMethod.Invoke(RowValue, null).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Key, Value);
    }
}
```

OR, **List of Dictionary**

```
var MyArray = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>() {
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "id", "1" }, { "cell1", "cell 1 row 1 Data" }, { "cell2", "cell 2 row 1 Data" } },
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "id", "2" }, { "cell1", "cell 1 row 2 Data" }, { "cell2", "cell 2 row 2 Data" } },
    new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "id", "3" }, { "cell1", "cell 1 row 3 Data" }, { "cell2", "cell 2 row 3 Data" } }
};
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> Item in MyArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row Start");
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> props in Item)
    {
        var Key = props.Key;
        var Value = props.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", Key, Value);
    }
}
```

Good luck..

Answer (score 4):

Use Reflection to do this

```
SomeClass A = SomeClass(...)
PropertyInfo[] properties = A.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 0):

A small word of caution, if "do some stuff" means updating the value of the actual property that you visit AND if there is a struct type property along the path from root object to the visited property, the change you made on the property will not be reflected on the root object.

Answer (score 0):

A copy-paste solution (extension methods) mostly based on earlier responses to this question.

Also properly handles IDicitonary (ExpandoObject/dynamic) which is often needed when dealing with this reflected stuff.

**Not recommended for use in tight loops and other hot paths. In those cases you're gonna need some caching/IL emit/expression tree compilation.**

```
    public static IEnumerable<(string Name, object Value)> GetProperties(this object src)
    {
        if (src is IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
        {
            return dictionary.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value));
        }
        return src.GetObjectProperties().Select(x => (x.Name, x.GetValue(src)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetObjectProperties(this object src)
    {
        return src.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().GetParameters().Any());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to change GetProperties() to GetRuntimeProperties().

```
  static void EnumObject(ShareCollection obj)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            property.GetValue(obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get any of the above ways to work, but this worked. The username and password for DirectoryEntry are optional.

```
   private List<string> getAnyDirectoryEntryPropertyValue(string userPrincipalName, string propertyToSearchFor)
    {
        List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            int index = userPrincipalName.IndexOf("@");
            string originatingServer = userPrincipalName.Remove(0, index + 1);
            string path = "LDAP://" + originatingServer; //+ @"/" + distinguishedName;
            DirectoryEntry objRootDSE = new DirectoryEntry(path, PSUsername, PSPassword);
            var objSearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(objRootDSE);
            objSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(UserPrincipalName={0}))", userPrincipalName);
            SearchResultCollection properties = objSearcher.FindAll();

            ResultPropertyValueCollection resPropertyCollection = properties[0].Properties[propertyToSearchFor];
            foreach (string resProperty in resPropertyCollection)
            {
                returnValue.Add(resProperty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            returnValue.Add(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```