# C# Dynamically add columns to DataTable for each Object Property

Tags: c#, struct, datatable, properties, datacolumn

When I try to use [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893050/5825579) to dynamically add columns to my DataTable, the `if` condition is never true. I have tried changing the `struct` to a `class` and I have tried with and without the `BindingFlags` on the `GetProperties`. What am I missing?

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    public DataTable DeviceDataTable;
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AttachToTable(new TestObject());
    }
    public void AttachToTable(params object[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data[i].GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Length > DeviceDataTable.Columns.Count)
                foreach (PropertyInfo info in data[i].GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
                {
                    DeviceDataTable.Columns.Add(info.Name, data[i].GetType());
                }
        }
        DeviceDataTable.Rows.Add(data);
    }
    public struct TestObject
    {
        public static readonly string Porperty_One = "First property";
        public static readonly string Porperty_Two = "Second property";
        public static readonly string Porperty_Three = "Third property";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sample struct is bad because it has no properties, not even instance fields but only static fields. So your Type.GetProperties won't return them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are correct! Adding `get; set;` to the `TestObject` properties and removing `static readonly` solved the problem. I did not know that `GetProperties()` did not return `static readonly` strings. If you elaborate your answer I will mark it as accepted anser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample struct is bad because it has no properties, not even instance but only static fields. So `Type.GetProperties` won't return them. This should work as intended:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public string PorpertyOne   => "First property";
    public string PorpertyTwo   => "Second property";
    public string PorpertyThree => "Third property";
}
```