# Get Property Value from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class MagicMetadata
{
  public string DataLookupField { get; set; }
  public string DataLookupTable { get; set; }
  public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And an instance of it, let's say:

```
MagicMetadata md = new MagicMetadata
{
  DataLookupField = "Engine_Displacement",
  DataLookupTable = "Vehicle_Options",
  Tags = new List<String>{"a","b","c"}
}
```

Given the `MagicMetadata` instance, I need to create a new object for each property, e.g.:

```
public class FormMetadataItem 
{
  public string FormFieldName { get; set; }
  public string MetadataLabel { get; set; }
}
```

So I am trying something like this as per [c# foreach (property in object)... Is there a simple way of doing this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893028/c-sharp-foreach-property-in-object-is-there-a-simple-way-of-doing-this)

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in md.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   new FormMetaData
   {
     FormFieldName = propertyInfo.Name,
     MetadataLabel = propertyInfo.GetValue(metadata.Name) //This doesn't work
   }
}
```

What I don't understand is how I get the value for the property that I am looping through. I don't understand the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) at all. Why do I need to pass it the object? What object?

P.S. I looked through the existing answers here, and I don't see a clear answer.

Comment: "At all ?".. It clearly states to pass the object instance. Why are you passing a string

Comment: The `PropertyInfo` class holds metadata about the property. It can help you get the value if you tell it the object it should get it from. The object you need to pass needs to be a valid instance.

Comment: @Greggz Yea, "at all", it didn't initially click that this was basically the equivalent of javascript's `someObject['somePropName']`

Comment: @Greggz Yea, close, though, I don't think the second `null` param is necessary in that example, at a guess. I will probably delete this. Edit: Can't delete once there is an answer.

Comment: @VSO It's probably a deprecated feature. Still they refer to the same problem and have the same solution. Better leave it for the time being, still you got points for it so

Comment: @Greggz I really don't care about the points. Would probably be cleaner to delete it as you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update to:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in md.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   new FormMetaData
   {
     FormFieldName = propertyInfo.Name,
     MetadataLabel = propertyInfo.GetValue(md) // <--
   }
}
```

`PropertyInfo.GetValue()` expects an **instance** of the object that
contains the property whose value you're trying to get. In your
`foreach` loop, that instance seems to be `md`.

---

Also note the distinction between `property` and `field` in C#. Properties are the members that have `get` and/or `set`:

```
class MyClass {
    string MyProperty {get; set;} // This is a property
    string MyField; // This is a field
}
```

And while reflecting, you need to access these members separately via the [`myObj.GetType().GetProperties()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`myObj.GetType().GetFields()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Comment: Hmm, I think I get it now - was way simpler than I thought, but didn't click for me. Thank you!

Comment: but how would this work out for the value of the `Tags` property, which is of type `List<string>`? what does OP actually need to show as their MetadataLabel?

Comment: @dlatikay I appreciate the concern, but once I get the property, I can figure out a way to handle the types. My main concern was getting via reflection. I will figure out the rest later.