# Initializing an array based on the present values

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to initialize an c# array. I don't know in advance how many values I am going to store on it. I know that this number will be between 0 and 5.

Is this the best approach to do this?

```
private CompiledRuleMethod CompileRuleMethod(Rule r)
{
  int sizeParameters = 0;
  if (r.Param1 != "") sizeParameters++;
  if (r.Param2 != "") sizeParameters++;
  if (r.Param3 != "") sizeParameters++;
  if (r.Param4 != "") sizeParameters++;
  if (r.Param5 != "") sizeParameters++;
  object[] parameters = new object[sizeParameters];
  if (r.Param1 != "") parameters[0] = r.Param1;
  if (r.Param2 != "") parameters[1] = r.Param2;
  if (r.Param3 != "") parameters[2] = r.Param3;
  if (r.Param4 != "") parameters[3] = r.Param4;
  if (r.Param5 != "") parameters[4] = r.Param5;

  return new CompiledRuleMethod(DelegateFactory.Create(typeof(RuleMethod).GetMethod(r.MethodName)),parameters);
}
```

I am pretty sure that isn't.

Comment: Why `parameters` is a `object[]` whereas the `ParamX`s are all strings?

Comment: Is the `ParamX`, properties from `r`, really look alike? Could we use reflexion to find all properties of `r` then filter, and map the value to an array? With some like [foreach(property p in object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893028/c-sharp-foreach-property-in-object-is-there-a-simple-way-of-doing-this)

Comment: what is r? why dont you make a method like "r.size()" that check all those params internally?

Comment: Do you really need an array ? If you don't know in advance how many elements will be stored, use a List instead.

Comment: No, it's not. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: parameters is a object[] because the aim is that this parameter can be of different types (string, int...). At the moment, only strings are accepted.

Comment: I am obtaining parameters to invoke a method dinamically. This parameters I have to pass into a object[]. This parameters can be of different types, but as are obtained via DB, initially are strings. I will have to think about how to convert it to the appropiate type. But I think this is irrelevant for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your current code doesn't actually work. If, say, only `Param4` is empty, then `sizeParameters` is 4. And then you create a `parameters` array of length 4. However, when the execution reaches the last line, it will try to put `Param5` into index 4 of the array, causing an `IndexOutofRangeException`.

It seems like you just want to filter out those params that are empty, and keep the ones that are not empty.

You can first put all of the params you want into an array:

```
var unfilteredParams = new[] {r.Param1, r.Param2, r.Param3, r.Param4, r.Param5};
```

And then use `Where` to filter it:

```
var filteredParams = unfilteredParams.Where(x => x != "").ToArray();
```

Comment: `.Cast<object>()` since we want `object[] parameters`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Declaring the type of `filteredParams` as `object[]` works as well, since `ToArray` is generic, but I don't see why the OP would want an object array instead.

Comment: @Sweeper, you are right. But i am going to ensure that always the parameters are going to be filled in order. I mean, if for example Param3 is empty, Param4 and Param5 will be empty.

Comment: Yes, I tested and it works perfectly. Now I have to work on type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array. List is more appropriate if you don't know how many items it will need. Then you can use list.Add(r.Param) to append items. Though without more context it's hard to say what is the best approach.