# Adjust all properties of a specified type on an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Working on a C# ASP.NET MVC web app that stores a specified "decimal accuracy" for each user, that affects how the app displays certain fields. For values that are displayed to the user, the previous dev would just use something like this before returning:

```
// Create output "DisplayObject" & assign values to its properties
// Fetch user's preferred "userAccuracy"
...
displayObject.val1 = Math.Round(displayObject.val1, userAccuracy);
displayObject.val2 = Math.Round(displayObject.val2, userAccuracy);
displayObject.val3 = Math.Round(displayObject.val3, userAccuracy);
...
return View(displayObject);
```

For objects with a lot of fields, this is a bit clunky-looking. Was wondering if there was an easy way to say, "iterate through an object and round any fields that are of type `decimal` to `userAccuracy` decimal places" or similar. Found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893028/c-sharp-foreach-property-in-object-is-there-a-simple-way-of-doing-this#answer-9893050) to a resource that showed how to achieve this via reflection, but I've heard that usage of reflection should be limited to where necessary, as it can be quite slow.

*Edit*: For clarity's sake "displayObject" was just an example return. For different controller methods, there'll be different return types that don't really have any common properties. The only similarity, is that for certain returned objects, I'll want a straightforward way of rounding all `decimal` properties on those objects to the specified accuracy. I'm thinking at this point that I'll either have to keep using the previous dev's strategy of just rounding every decimal value that'll be displayed, or measure & assess how costly just using reflection will be.

One other alternative I've thought of is just having a `round_all` method on each of the objects I'm returning to display-- it'll just be moving the existing chunk of code elsewhere, but if I have to return the same object more than once it'll be useful (and clears up the MVC controllers a bit of more-or-less unrelated code).

Comment: search for the term `extension methods`

Comment: This sounds like a presentation concern and you should probably be doing it in the view, not the controller... You *could* use Reflection for this, although it can be slow so if you have many properties may not be ideal unless you cache the acessors